# Big Query, multiple unnest no duplicates

Tags: google-bigquery

need help in removing the duplicates from the result in Google Big Query.
I have put some sample data in the CTE and my attempt to remove duplicates

```sql
WITH
  make_table AS (
  SELECT
    1 AS id,
    '[{"key": "value1"}, {"key": "value2"}, {"key": "value3"}]' AS a_col,
    '[1,2,3]' AS b_col 
)
SELECT
  id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(a_col_individual, '$.key') AS `key`,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(b_col_individual, '$') AS `value`
FROM
  make_table AS mt,
  UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(mt.a_col)) AS a_col_individual,
  UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(mt.b_col)) AS b_col_individual
```

[image]

These results show up like the image above, but what I need is in the table below, as you can see the value column is repeated for every row in the key column

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | value1 | 1 |
| 1 | value2 | 2 |
| 1 | value3 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`WITH OFFSET`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays) in BigQuery array like below

```sql
WITH
  make_table AS (
  SELECT
    1 AS id,
    '[{"key": "value1"}, {"key": "value2"}, {"key": "value3"}]' AS a_col,
    '[1,2,3]' AS b_col 
)
SELECT
  id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(a_col_individual, '$.key') AS `key`,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(b_col_individual, '$') AS `value`
FROM
  make_table AS mt,
  UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(mt.a_col)) AS a_col_individual WITH offset JOIN
  UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(mt.b_col)) AS b_col_individual WITH offset USING (offset);
```

**Query results**

[image]